# How to make countdown on the same line

Tags: countdown

I am very new to coding. Right now each number prints on a new line but I need each
part of the sequence to print one after the other on the same line..Please help!

```
import time
print ("Starting countdown... ")
for i in range (10,0,-1):
    print (i)
    time.sleep(1)
print ("Blast off!")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something called Carriage Return, which moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, without moving it to a new one.  This one is printed like "\r".

So, just replace your

```
print(i)
```

with

```
print("\r", i, end="")
```

The end="" is needed because print, be default, will go to the next line and you do not want that.

Comment: Any way to delete cruft from the previous print? If I print `1234` then `567` I'll get `5674`.

Comment: Fill it up with extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

You have to use end in your print statement, how you're going to end it. By default it is tends to new line (\n) so you need to explicitly define the ending of the print as below,

```
import time
print ("Starting countdown... ")
for i in range (10,0,-1):
    print (i, end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
print ("Blast off!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code would will print the numbers in the same line with a space:

```
import time

print("Starting countdown... ")
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print(i, end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
print()
print("Blast off!")
```

**output:**

```
Starting countdown... 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
Blast off!
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

In **print()** replace **end='\n'** to **end=' '**

```
import time
print ("Starting countdown... ")
for i in range (10,0,-1):
    print (i, end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
print ("Blast off!")
```